# PHPUnit check expects with argument after trigger

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class that builds a hierarchy (to be extended).  When a new object is created it takes as an argument in the constructor its parent object.  The constructor of the object being created then lets that parent know that it is now its child.  Simplified as follows:

```
abstract class Hierarchy {

    private $children;

    public function __construct(Hierarchy $parent = null) {
        if ($parent) { $parent->addChild($this); }
    }

    protected function addChild(Hierarchy $child) {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

}
```

Now to test this I have the following code:

```
$parent = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->setMethods(['addChild'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$parent->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addChild');

$child = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->setConstructorArgs([$parent])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();
```

What I want to be able to test though is that the instance of $child being created is passed to the $parent addChild, so I really want this:

```
$parent->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addChild')
    ->with($this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
        ->setConstructorArgs([$parent])
        ->getMockForAbstractClass());
```

But that does not work.  I get "Mocked method does not exist."  (Which makes sense, sort of a chicken and egg - check the instance before it is created but need to use the instance to check...)

**So is there anyway to get a deferred object from expects and check that it was called with a certain argument after the fact?**

Sort of like this:

```
$parent = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->setMethods(['addChild'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$deferred = $parent->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addChild');

$child = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->setConstructorArgs([$parent])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$deferred->wasCalledWith($child);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
$parent = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->setMethods(['addChild'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$child = $this->getMockBuilder('Hierarchy')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['__construct'])
    ->getMockForAbstractClass();

$parent->expects($this->once())
    ->method('addChild')
    ->with($child);

$child->__construct($parent);
```